# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). Working in local machine (chrome browser) but not production and other browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-redux

**Error:- Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

**It's working on my local machine (chrome browser) but not in production as well in other browser. Here I am confused**

**Below is my Cart Reducer State (Using Redux)**

```
const cart = {
  cartItems: [],
  shippingAddress:{},
  paymentMethod:{}
}
```

```
const PlaceorderScreen = ({ history }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
  const { userInfo } = userLogin

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart)
  const { cartItems, shippingAddress, paymentMethod } = cart
  console.log(cartItems)

  const placeOrder = useSelector((state) => state.placeOrder)

  const { success, order } = placeOrder
```

**When I removed the calculations part then it's work fine in local as well in production.**

**Here I am doing the calculations then adding to my cart object.**

```
  // calculations
  const addDecimals = (num) => {
    return (Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
  }

  let cost = 0
  cartItems.map((product) => {
    cost = product.price * product.qty + cost
  })
  cart.itemsPrice = addDecimals(Number(cost))

  cart.taxPrice = addDecimals(Number((0.15 * cart.itemsPrice).toFixed(2)))
  cart.shippingPrice = addDecimals(cart.itemsPrice > 100 ? 0 : 100)

  cart.totalPrice = (
    Number(cart.itemsPrice) +
    Number(cart.shippingPrice) +
    Number(cart.taxPrice)
  ).toFixed(2)
```

**After inserting the calculations in cart. My cart object look like this.**

```
cart: {
    cartItems: [
      {
        ...
      }
    ],
    shippingAddress: {
      address: 'ddd',
      city: 'ddd',
      postalCode: '33',
      country: 'dd'
    },
    paymentMethod: 'Paypal',
    itemsPrice: '59.99',
    taxPrice: '9.00',
    shippingPrice: '100.00',
    totalPrice: '168.99'
  },
```

**After the calculations to cart object I am accessing them here. Problem occurs in this block. When I remove Cart_Summary then it works fine.**

```
 <div className="Cart_Summary">
        <p className="Cart_Summar">Cart Summary</p>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col1">
            <p>Item price</p>
            <p>Shipping price</p>
            <p>Tax price</p>
            <p>Total price</p>
            <br></br>
            <p>PaymentMethod</p>
          </div>
          <div className="col2">
            <p>${cart.itemsPrice}</p>
            <p>${cart.shippingPrice}</p>
            <p>${cart.taxPrice}</p>
            <p>${cart.totalPrice}</p>
            <br></br>
            <p>{paymentMethod}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={placeOrderHandler}>Place Order</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's because of paymentMethod:{}, so it's get treated like object before it gets initialized with string value.

Comment: Actually  I am a beginner, means it's due the empty object? and I am passing string but it's object that's why it's giving error? Can you explain me more about it?

Comment: Correct. You need to make an empty string it's initial state (instead of empty object).
Or you could implement additional check 
{typeof paymentMethod === 'object' ? null : paymentMethod}
or
{typeof paymentMethod !== 'object' && paymentMethod}